# Backup and restore ChrUbuntu on Chromebook

Tags: filesystem, backup, tar

I recently installed ChrUbuntu (14.04, Tegra K1, nyan_blaze) onto a 22GB partition on the Chrome OS 32GB SSD using the ChrUbuntu script [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-NLleDS4IRqR0gtQzJFdGpseFk?usp=sharing)

I would like to test a backup and restore using TAR.

Instructions can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR)

I understand that `tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /` creates a compressed copy of the of the required filesystem.

And that `cat *tar.gz* | tar -xvpzf - -C /` restores it.

Question: is the restored filesystem an exact snapsnot? i.e. if I've updated the filesystem with new applications and programs and configuration settings, are these new branches and leaf nodes completely removed when restoring?

Comment: I answered the on-topic part of your question and removed the off-topic part of it. The ChrUbuntu boot process is not supported officially and therefore off topic here. However you can ask about any Linux distribution on [Unix.SE].

Answer (score 2):

**No**, after unpacking the Tar archive the file system will *not be the same*.

**However**, the directory structure and the content of all extracted files will be exactly the same meaning that, while not the same, the result is *semantically equivalent*. Since that includes all installed programs and configurations this seems to be all you're interested in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The system will need some sort of boot loader in order to boot any OS's that are installed to it, and that's what GRUB is, so yes, you will need to perform that step.  As for your first question, the tar command will backup every file in the directory you are running tar from.  This is why the first command is "`cd /`", which navigates the terminal to the root directory of the drive, and also why you must add "`--exclude=/backup.tar.gz`" to the backup command, because without it, tar will try and backup the newly created tar.gz, which would cause errors.

--edit--
Another alternative is using the `dd` command, which will clone an entire hard drive or directory, if you have the storage space to keep it.  This will take longer than the tar command, because it copies every bit on the drive, including empty space, so you will need an external drive that is larger than your system drive.

```
 `sudo dd if=/dev/sdX of=/path/to/backup.img`
```

(where sdX is the name of the source drive, you can list them with `lsblk`)

To restore, simply reverse the backup command:

`sudo dd if=/path/to/backup.img of=/dev/sdX`

Edit-
Sorry, I forgot to mention that you must perform the DD command from a live disc.